# Changing order of summation and taking the limit - infinite series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have trouble showing that a infinite series is differentiable.
Second, when is it possible to change the order of summation and taking the limit?

Specifically I have trouble solving these problems, where the issue arises:

Consider the function $F(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (n x)}{3^{n}+x^{2}}$.

a) Show that F is differentiable
b) Show that $F(x) \rightarrow 0$ for $x \rightarrow \infty$

---

a) I know that I need to show that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n' $ converges uniformly, and then I can use a theorem to show that F is differentiable by $ F'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n' $.

However, I have trouble finding the converging majorant series.

$f_n'=-\frac{\sin (n x) n}{3^{n}+x^{2}}-\frac{\cos (n x)}{\left(3^{n}+x^{2}\right)^{2}}2x$

$\left|f_{n}^{\prime}(x)\right|=\left|\frac{\sin (n x) n}{3^{n}+x^{2}}+\frac{\cos (n x)}{\left(3^{n}+x^{2}\right)^{2}} 2 x\right| \leq \frac{|\sin (n x)| n}{3^{n}+x^{2}}+\frac{|2 x \cos (n x)|}{\left(3^{n}+x^{2}\right)^{2}} \leq \frac{n}{3^{n}+x^{2}}+\frac{2|x|}{\left(3^{n}+x^{2}\right)^{2}}$

I think the term to the far right is bounded. But do they really want me to analyze that function and find it's maximum (differentiate and find maxima, and analyze as $x\rightarrow \infty$?)
If it's bounded by $M$ we could have. $|f_n'|\leq\frac{n}{3^{n}}+m=M_n$,  $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.
And by quotient criteria, the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}M_n$ would converge if $q=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{M_{n+1}}{M_{n}}=\frac{1}{3}+m<1$

But there must be an easier, faster and more obvious way?

b)
Here I probably need to argue why I can move a limit inside an infinite sum $\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} F(x)=\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (n x)}{3^{n}+x^{2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\cos (n x)}{3^{n}+x^{2}}$.

However, I do not have any theorem telling me when it's possible to do that. (Note I have shown that F converges uniformly in a previous problem if that's relevant for when you can change limits).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test).

You can prove following inequalities for all $x \in \mathbb R$
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{3^n +x^2} &\le \frac{1}{3^n}\\
\frac{\vert x \vert}{3^n +x^2} &\le 1
\end {cases}$$

Then based on what you already found:

$$\begin{aligned}
\left|f_{n}^{\prime}(x)\right| &\leq \frac{n}{3^{n}+x^{2}}+\frac{2|x|}{\left(3^{n}+x^{2}\right)^{2}}\\
&\leq \frac{n}{3^n} + \frac{2}{3^n+x^2}\\
&\leq \frac{3n}{3^n}
\end{aligned}$$

and the last series is convergent.

Comment: How does that help me? I don't see the system. It's not obious to me, what $\frac{2|x|}{\left(3^{n}+x^{2}\right)^{2}}$ is smaller than. My m needs to satisfy $m<2/3$.

Comment: See additional elements.

Comment: Thank very much. But I would still have to prove the inequality $\frac{\vert x \vert}{3^n +x^2} \leq 2 $. Would you do that by finding the maximum of the function by differentiating?

And I would probably still use the ratio test for the series with $5n/3^n$

Comment: Just separate the cases $x \le 1$ and $x \ge 1$. In the  later case $x \le x^2$.